# How does Guice inject typesafe config?

Tags: scala, sbt, guice, sbt-assembly, typesafe-config

Recently I am reading some scala code which uses Guice to inject the Typesafe Config.. It seems kind of magic to me how this works.. My question is, how to interpret this code? Does Guice inject all those configuration values read in sbt-assembly into typesafe config automatically?

Scala code:

```
class FooImpl @Inject() (
  config: Config
) extends Foo {

  private val myConfig = "section.foo"

  override val batchSize = config.getInt(s"$myConfig.batchSize")

  .....
}
```

In Setting.scala

```
object Settings {
    ...
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case "prod.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
      case x =>
        val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
        oldStrategy(x)
    }
  ...
```

In prod.conf

```
section {

  foo {
    batchSize = 10000
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mixing three different mechanisms here :)

1. @Inject is indeed Guice, and it's a final step in the process. Simply put, Guice has a "dependency injection container" that knows where to look for instances of certain types. One of the types it knows of is the `Config`. *How* it knows this depends on the framework you're using (or how you instantiate your Guice container if you're not using it);
2. Typesafe config has rules on where to look for configuration. [Readme](https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior) sums it pretty good, but in short - it finds application.conf in resources folder (or, actually, anywhere on the classpath), and then imports all the other files that `application.conf` explicitly imports (using `import other_conf.conf`). I'm assuming in your case there's `import prod.conf` somewhere in the `application.conf`
3. Assembly - just puts all the resources from all the dependencies into one giant resource folder - specifying rules on what to do if there are multiple files wit hthe same name. In your case, it tells it to just concatenate them.

Comment: Thanks @J0HN  for your reply in detail. Yes I think I got these three individual concept. What I am confused is how these three components (resource file -> Typesafe config -> Guice) work together. Can I say that (step-1) Assembly put all the resources file together; (step-2) Typesafe config read in those files; (step-3) Somehow magically Guice inject that TypeSafe Config instance into our class (in my case it is FooImpl.class)..

Comment: @batilei Yes, with a tiny alterations :) (step-1) assembly put all the resources _onto classpath_; (step-2) typesafe looks up config files (at least the application.conf, and then all the imports from it) _on the classpath_; (step-3) guice somehow gets an instance of the config, and then injects as it normally does. How it gets it depends on the framework, but it is basically some variant of either `bind[Config].toInstance` or `bind[Config].toProvider`; in any case, Config.loadConfig is invoked. If you could share which framework you're using I might be able to tell how (step-3) is done.

Comment: Thank you @J0HN for explanation in detail. Yup I think I got the big picture although not sure the "magic" yet. Could you please provide some insight regarding "which framework you're using" ? Framework of guice or? Thank you.

Comment: Application development framework - Playframework, akka-http, Spring, Scalatra, etc.?

Comment: Hi, so sorry for replying late. Actually I am not sure. It seems Playframework to me (not so familiar with Play, definitely not Spring, akka-http)..The related dependencies in sbt are
(1) "com.google.inject.extensions" % "guice-assistedinject"  and 
(2) "net.codingwell"   %% "scala-guice"

Comment: Do you have `conf` folder and `routes` file in it? If yes - definitely Play :) In play, the way it is loaded is some interplay between https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala and https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/core/play-guice/src/main/java/play/inject/guice/GuiceBuilder.java - unfortunately turns out I'm not that familiar with the internals of play to tell better :)

Comment: Hi J0HN, it is very helpful. Thank you so much.